# Почему функция поиска родителей отрабатывает по разному?

Tags: php

*Сразу хотел бы извиниться за "портянку", но не нашёл как сворачивать куски кода*

Столкнулся с проблемой, от которой уже мозги кипят:

В первом случае получаю данные из бд, вот **var_dump()** данных:

`array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(20) "Информация"
    ["set_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["is_category"]=>
    int(1)
    ["code"]=>
    string(11) "information"
    ["sort"]=>
    int(10)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["level"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "О нас"
    ["set_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["is_category"]=>
    int(1)
    ["code"]=>
    string(5) "about"
    ["sort"]=>
    int(10)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["level"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(12)
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "История"
    ["set_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["is_category"]=>
    int(0)
    ["code"]=>
    string(7) "history"
    ["sort"]=>
    int(10)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["level"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}`

А это для сравнения **var_dump()** массива, с которым всё отрабатывает как надо:

`array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "NODE"
    ["payment"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "NODE 1"
    ["payment"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "NODE 1-1"
    ["payment"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "NODE 1-1-1"
    ["payment"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(6)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "NODE 1-1-2"
    ["payment"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "NODE 2"
    ["payment"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(7)
    ["parent_id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "NODE 2-1"
    ["payment"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}`

Т.е. массивы по структуре одинаковые.

Сам код:

```
function getBranches($arr, $id) {
    $childrenArr = array();
    foreach($arr as $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id']==$id) {
            $childrenArr[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $childrenArr;
}

function getBranch($arr, $id) {
    $branch = array();
    foreach($arr as $item) {

        if ($item['id'] == $id) {
            $branch[$item['id']] = $item;
            $branches = getBranches($arr, $id);
            $children = array();
            foreach($branches as $child) {
                $b = getBranch($arr, $child['id']);
                foreach ($b as $token => $child) {
                    $children[$child['id']] = $child;
                }
            }
            $branch[$item['id']]['children'] = $children;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (count($branch)==0) echo 'WARNING '.$id;
    return $branch;
}
```

(ссылка на [песочницу](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7add407d78fc52a70c5a400352a5e959c4f54c08))

Для рабочего варианта `var_dump(getBranch($users,1))` создаёт правильную структуру, т.е. возвращает многомерный массив с правильно выстроенными детьми.

А вот для `var_dump(getBranch($users2,12))` данных из базы - берёт только активный элемент.

В чём может быть подвох? Весь вечер вчера убил - на пойму в чём может быть дело :(

Или подскажите рабочий код построения дерева с вложенной структурой из родителей по полю **parent_id**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась написанием другой функции:

```php
$users = [
  // DB Data
];
$arr = [];

function findParent($haystack, $needle) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if ($item['id'] == $needle) return $item;
    }
}

function makeParentTree($haystack, $array, $needle) {
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $item) {
        if ($item['id'] == $needle && $item['parent_id'] == 0 ) {
            $root = $item;
            $root['children'] = $array;
            $array = $root;
        } else if ($item['id'] == $needle) {
            $array = findParent($haystack, $item['parent_id']);
            $array['children'] = $item;
            $array = makeParentTree($haystack, $array, $array['parent_id']);
            break;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

var_dump(makeParentTree($users, $arr, 4));
```